# How to filter array in ng-repeat on the basis of specific attribute in that json array and ng-model value of other drop down in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to list cities based on their emirates using angularJS. That means when a emirate is selected from one drop down then the city drop down is filtered with the `ng-model` value of emirate. But the problem is filtering works but some cities' unique id are matched with a region id. For example if I select "Ras al-Khaimah" from the emirate drop down then its city "Ras al-Khaimah" appears in city drop down but "Fujairah" also appears there because the unique id of "Fujairah"  is same as the unique id of "Ras al-Khaimah". So  how can I filter specific fields of city JSON array in `ng-repeat` with the `ng-model` value of emirate? Please check my JSON array and my code is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.emriates = [ 
    { "region_id": "1", "region_name": "Abu Dhabi" },
    { "region_id": "2", "region_name": "Ajman" },
    { "region_id": "3", "region_name": "Dubai" },
    { "region_id": "4", "region_name": "Fujairah" },
    { "region_id": "5", "region_name": "Ras al-Khaimah" },
    { "region_id": "6", "region_name": "Sharja" },
    { "region_id": "7", "region_name": "Umm al-Quwain" }
  ];
  
  $scope.cities = [
    { "city_id": "2", "region_id": "1", "city_name": "Abudhabi" },
    { "city_id": "3", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Dubai" },
    { "city_id": "4", "region_id": "2", "city_name": "Ajman" },
    { "city_id": "5", "region_id": "4", "city_name": "Fujairah" },
    { "city_id": "6", "region_id": "5", "city_name": "Ras al-Khaimah" },
    { "city_id": "7", "region_id": "6", "city_name": "Sharja" },
    { "city_id": "8", "region_id": "7", "city_name": "Umm al-Quwain" },
    { "city_id": "9", "region_id": "1", "city_name": "Al Ain" },
    { "city_id": "10", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Jabel Ali" },
    { "city_id": "11", "region_id": "6", "city_name": "kalba" },
    { "city_id": "13", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Jumeirah" },
    { "city_id": "14", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Musaffah" }
  ];
});
</script>

<html>
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
      <label>Emirate
        <select ng-model="emriate">
          <option value="">-Select-</option>
          <option ng-repeat="emt in emriates" value="{emt.region_id}}">                
            {{emt.region_name}}
          </option>
      </select>
     </label>
   </div>
   <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <label>City
        <select ng-model="city">
          <option value="">-Select-</option>
          <option ng-repeat="cit in cities | filter:emriate" value="{cit.city_id}}">
            {{cit.city_name}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to use a more accurate filter ;)

You want to use `filter:{'region_id': emriate}` instead of `filter:emriate`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.emriates=[ 
{ "region_id": "1", "region_name": "Abu Dhabi" },
 { "region_id": "2", "region_name": "Ajman" },
  { "region_id": "3", "region_name": "Dubai" },
   { "region_id": "4", "region_name": "Fujairah" },
    { "region_id": "5", "region_name": "Ras al-Khaimah" },
     { "region_id": "6", "region_name": "Sharja" },
      { "region_id": "7", "region_name": "Umm al-Quwain" }
       ];

$scope.cities=[ 
{ "city_id": "2", "region_id": "1", "city_name": "Abudhabi" },
 { "city_id": "3", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Dubai" },
  { "city_id": "4", "region_id": "2", "city_name": "Ajman" },
   { "city_id": "5", "region_id": "4", "city_name": "Fujairah" },
    { "city_id": "6", "region_id": "5", "city_name": "Ras al-Khaimah" },
     { "city_id": "7", "region_id": "6", "city_name": "Sharja" },
      { "city_id": "8", "region_id": "7", "city_name": "Umm al-Quwain" },
       { "city_id": "9", "region_id": "1", "city_name": "Al Ain" },
        { "city_id": "10", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Jabel Ali" },
         { "city_id": "11", "region_id": "6", "city_name": "kalba" },
          { "city_id": "13", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Jumeirah" },
           { "city_id": "14", "region_id": "3", "city_name": "Musaffah" },
            { "city_id": "15", "region_id": "10", "city_name": "Error 1" }
           ];
           
$scope.exactFilter = function(value) {
  return value.region_id === $scope.emriate;
};

});


</script>

<htmL>
 <body>
  <div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div>
    <label>Emriate
     <select ng-model="emriate">
      <option value="">-Select-</option>
      <option ng-repeat="emt in emriates" value="{{emt.region_id}}">{{emt.region_name}}</option>
     </select>
    </label>
   </div>
   <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <label>City
     <select ng-model="city">
      <option value="">-Select-</option>
      <option ng-repeat="cit in cities | filter:exactFilter" value="{{cit.city_id}}">{{cit.city_name}}</option>
     </select>
    </label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</htmL>
```

According to the documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), if you use a string as the filter input, every attribute can be used to match the value referenced by this string, so you want to pass a more accurate filter with an object to specify the format to perform the filtering.

**EDIT**

Here is the solution: just add to your scope a filtering function:

```
$scope.exactFilter = function(value) {
  return value.region_id === $scope.emriate;
};
```

Then use it as the filter.

Really, please check the AngularJS documentation, everything is in there ;)

Comment: There is some error above answer that is i  add some cities to cities json array that have region_id have 10,11, and 101   receptively. the problem is  when i select "Abu Dhabi" from first drop down that region_id  is 1 then second dropdown there appear cities  error1,error2 and error3 that cities region_id is not 1.Please check this Codepen link : https://codepen.io/sheringreen/pen/rrdWKj?editors=1010  and please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Please check above problem

Comment: Did you check the link to the documentation? Because the answer is there ;) But hey, i'm probably too nice. I'm gonna edit my answer.